# Creating Runtime content programmatically with ArcObjects?

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-10.2, arcgis-runtime

I'm exploring different options for creating an offline mobile application with Esri's technologies. The option that fits my needs the best is to use the ArcGIS Runtime SDK with offline maps created with ArcGIS for Desktop(In ArcMap : File->ShareAs->Runtime Content).

The next step is now to automate the Runtime Content creation. Is there a way, using ArcObjects, to create Runtime content programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally was able to create Runtime Content within ArcObjects. As jdONeil suggested, I used the [Create Runtime Content](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000019n000000) GP tool in conjunction with's arcobject's ability to [call a geoprocessing tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//0001000003rr000000).

It worked like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of ways to automate the runtime content creation:

- [GP Tool in Desktop with python extensions](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000019n000000)

or

- [Runtime SDK's Offline services pattern against server/online](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/features/offline/)

Comment: It's the good tool, but I want to be able to call it(or something similar) from an ArcObjects dll

Comment: Unfortunately it is not support in ArcObjects at this time.